# Почему ширина input'а больше, чем ему полагается?

Tags: html, css

Делаю сайт в процентах и при вставке инпута в див уходит за границу. Никак не пойму в чем дело и как исправить. Хочу, чтобы интуп занимал все свои 10% и при масштабировании оставался на отведенном месте.

```
<div id="navigation">
<div class="inline-menu"> 
<div class="reg-link"><a href="#">Место под меню</a></div>
</div>

<div class="search"> 
<form action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Поиск">
</form> 
</div>
</div>

.CSS
#navigation {
clear:both; 
height:40px; 
margin:auto; 
padding-top:10px; 
border-bottom: 1px solid maroon;
background-color:#F0F0F0;}

.inline-menu {width:90%; float:left;}
.search {width:10%; float:left; }

input {width:100%;}
```

[image: результат]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По умолчанию браузеры плюсуют к ширине `input` еще и `padding` и `border`. Также по умолчанию есть и `margin`. Решается просто:

```
input {
  width: 100%;
  /* Убираем влияние padding и border на конечную ширину input */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Обнуляем margin */
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ещё не забывай про  *+border*

Comment: @Yuri box-sizing: border-box; поможет против бордера.